# processing form multiple times

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm helping to create a small 'game' where you will be able to take the traits from a male/female animal and create their offspring.

In the form you tell it what fur type/color etc the mother/father have and using random numbers it will generate the offspring.

However I need to generate a random amount of offspring, therefor I need to generate a random number and have the form create that many results!
Here's how a simple version of it looks for just one result: http://lostfables.com/counter/home.php

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/tBcNUSex

How do I essentially have that form be submitted multiple times depending on the random number I assign?

Comment: submit the form once. Then generate your random number on the server and create as many extra offspring as you need from that. Submitting the form multiple times will just create unnecessary HTTP traffic - the same data will get submitted each time, so it's pointless. Your pastebin code is pretty much doing this already, you just need to loop over the creation code however many times the random number says, by the looks of it.

Comment: Well the problem I have is that I don't know how to make it loop, exactly. I need the offspring to have new random numbers each time to allow for each to have varied fur type/color etc depending on the parents.

Comment: @Kamata, I've edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an extra variable for random `$numberOfIterations` and to wrap your logic code with a for loop. This will recreate the logic code business according to random `$check` for deciding on the current attribute, and at the end of every iteration it will print the current result.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // We want a random number between 1-200 and put it in the variable $check
    // Random number of loop times
    $numberOfIterations = rand(1,200);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfIterations; $i++) {
        // Random number for generating attributes.
        $check = rand(1,200);

        // All the logic code in here
        // ..
        // End of logic code

        echo '<br/><br/>';
        echo $check.'<br/>';
        echo $coats;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's giving me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC), expecting ')' in /homepages/9/d598718627/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LostFables/counter/home.php on line 58

Comment: I've forgotten a `$` at `$i++`